# aspnet core stop background running task

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, signalr, task

I have an api method which runs in background (async) for ~6 mins.
I want to allow the user to cancel it from another api request.

For Ex.

`/api/credits/post/25` will start the background task and returns OK response immediately.

`/api/credits/stop/25` will stop running background task.

my current code.

API

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CreditController : Controller
{
    private readonly CreditService _creditService;
    public CreditController (CreditService creditService)
    {
        _creditService = creditService;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public string Post(int id)
    {
        if (_creditService.Instances.Any(p => p.ID == id))
            return "already running " + id;
        _creditService.Post(id, (s,e) =>
        {
            // sending realtime changes to user using SignalR.
            // so that they will see progress and whats running in background 
        });
        return "started " + id;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public string Stop(int id)
    {
        var instance = _creditService.Instances.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == id));
        if (instance == null)
            return id + " is not running";
        instance.CancelToken.Cancel();
        return id + " stoppped";            
    }
}
```

Service

```
public class CreditService
{
    public static List<CreditService> Instances = new List<CreditService>();

    public Status<object> Status = new Status<object>();
    public CancellationTokenSource CancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public Task Post(int id, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = null)
    {
        Instances.Add(this);
        if (handler != null) Status.PropertyChanged += handler;

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                // long running task
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Status.Error = e.Message ?? e.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handler != null) Status.PropertyChanged -= handler;
                Status.Clear();
                CancelToken.Dispose();
                Instances.Remove(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is working as expected. but i want to know is this a good approach or is there any other better alternative to this.

Also this will not work if i use load balancer and multiple instances of application. How do i fix this.

Comment: you should look into using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Comment: The `List<T>` class is not thread safe. Long running tasks should not be executed in the context of a web application. Have a separate application responsible for processing long running tasks. The Hangfire tool that Joe mentioned is a good one - one of the best ways to use it is running in a console application as a Windows Service.

Comment: @mason Yes, i thought of creating separate app or service for it. So there is no other way?

Comment: There are certain tools, like Hangfire, that will let you run it directly in the web application. But that's not a good idea - it's going to take up threads that your web application could otherwise use. And it doesn't allow you to independently scale the website vs scaling the background worker. It really depends on how sophisticated this needs to be.

Comment: if i use Hangfire, how do i invoke `CancelToken` from another api request with out keeping its reference?

Comment: You wouldn't use a cancel token. You'd store state somewhere else, such as a database. When your job starts, check if the job still needs to be done or not.

Comment: i think i got it. i'll use redis to keep track of state instead of CancelToken, that way i don't need to store the instance reference in static class. Thank you.

Comment: Good idea - that will allow you to scale out for load balanced scenarios. Static classes that store state don't really work well for those scenarios